# Using RPC in IoT environments

Tags: mqtt, communication, wireless, fog-computing, 802.15

I would like to use RPC for communication between fog nodes. As the connection between the nodes is wireless (802.15.4), I don't want to use an RPC framework that uses HTTP (like gRPC).

I know that for such use cases, MQTT is used frequently. However, as the MQTT broker normally runs in the cloud, the nodes need to send data to the cloud which I would like to avoid.

I was looking into [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) which seems like a good choice. However, I would be interested if someone already has experience with using RPC in IoT environments and if there are any frameworks that you could recommend to me?

Comment: An MQTT broker does not have to be in the cloud and can be run on a local network, but it does require TCP.  So if you were to go that route, you would need to run MQTT-SN on the 802.15.4 network with a gateway to the MQTT broker.

Comment: Yes, an MQTT broker can run in the fog as well. However, as fog nodes can be very unstable, making the broker fault-tolerant is not always easy or possible. That's why I was curious if an RPC framework exists which is used in IoT environments.